# Alternatives to appending "new" for new versions of a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, naming-conventions

It drives me nuts when developers copy / paste existing code into a new proc, make some changes and then call it `dbo.<whatever the old name was>New`

They can also do this will all kinds of objects, but I decided to start with procs.

But I can't think of alternatives. I just know the word "new" becomes meaningless.

Can anyone provide alternatives or point to a book or url that does?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the solution depends on the reason why this is done.

If the reason is to keep some kind of backup/history, then the solution would be to keep that somewhere else. You would set up a short instruction for where to put the old versions, and how to document what it is.

If the reason is to keep two versions of the procedure, because one is still in use somewhere, or the time when to switch is hard to control, there may be some other options that let you keep the original name:

If you add fields to the result, you can add them at the end. Regardless of the code depends on the name or position of the fields, it can use the new result without change.

If parameters are added, a default can be provided that allows it to be called without it. If the original procedure is for example:

```
create procedure Company_GetAll
as
select CompanyId, Name from Company
```

You can add a parameter for filtering the result, that has a default that returns the unfiltered result:

```
create procedure Company_GetAll
  @Section int = null
as
select CompanyId, Name from Company
where Section = @Section or @Section is null
```

Comment: I am working with my manager to implement source control on the stored procs and other sourcecodified objects in the database.
Some people might balk at that, or try to keep it ok to update production without updating source control. Trying to think of a response to those kinds of responses for the meeting...Thanks!